# Появилась ошибка:Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

Изучаю Django по книжке и столкнулся с такой ошибкой:[image]

```
#Код learning_log/urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

Если требуется какой либо код пишите и задавайте вопросы(если что отвечу завтра(13.07).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас нигде не определён корневой путь. Поэтому на такой запрос сервер возвращает ответ с кодом `404`.

Добавьте его в `urls.py`, указав необходимое представление, и всё заработает:

```py
from django.urls import path
...

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ...),
    ...
]
```

На данный момент у Вас всего 2 пути:

1. `admin/` (из `urls.py`)
2. `topics/<int:topic_id>/` (из `learning_logs\urls.py`)

Comment: Как я понял вы про name?

Comment: @MZaytsev, нет... Я про то, что у Вас нет корневого пути. Простыми словами, Django не знает, что Вам показать, когда Вы заходите на корневую страницу сайта. Самая обыкновенная ошибка `404 Not Found`. Если Вы зайдёте на, к примеру, `admin/`, то ошибки не будет, потому что такой путь определён. Чтобы решить Вашу проблему, Вы должны определить пустой путь. Для определения любого пути также необходимо представление.